# In XSD schema 1.0 validation, any option available to check an element has any attributes?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, xsd-1.0

In the XSD file, for an element few attributes are given as optional. 
Need to validate if any of the listed attributes in available in the input XML file.

Comment: What would like to do? If I understand well, you would like to define a schema telling something like : "_for this element `foo-e`, I would like to have at either one of the following attributes `foo-att-1` or `foo-att-a2` or `foo-att-a3` set_"?

Comment: Yes , You are right. We can do this in xml schema 1.1 using xs:assert statement. But requirement is in 1.0.

Comment: Well in this case I'm afraid it won't possible with a pure Schema. May I suggest you to add [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) rules besides...

Comment: Because Schematron and XSD 1.1's assertion constraints are so general, it's fairly safe to say they'd work for you.  However, if you provide specific examples of XML that you wish to be valid and XML that you wish to be invalid, we might be able to find an acceptable XSD 1.0 solution to your particular problem.  You'll have to state it more precisely, though, for there to be any chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSD 1.0 **you can use *xs:key* in order to guarantee that an element has at least one attribute**. Example:

```
<xs:element name="elem">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="b" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="c" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="d" type="xs:int" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="attributePresent">
        <xs:selector xpath="." />
        <xs:field xpath="@*" />
    </xs:key>
</xs:element>
```

As an example, if you want to guarantee that at least one of *b* or *c* attributes are present in the element you can use

```
<xs:field xpath="@b | @c" />
```

Comment: Only works if only one attribute is specified--if more than one attribute is specified the validation fails.  Example XML: `<elem a="1" b="2" c="3" />` xmllint produces: `element elem: Schemas validity error : Element '{mynamespace}elem', attribute 'b': The XPath '@*' of a field of key identity-constraint '{mynamespace}attributePresent' evaluates to a node-set with more than one member.`  Same result using `<xs:field xpath="@b | @c" />`.